# C++ Searching Algorithm for the 1st number =n

Tags: c++, binary-search

I want an algorithm that works a similar way to binary search in which I have a number `n`, let's say 3, and an array as follows:

```
array[10] = {1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6}
```

I want the algorithm to return `p = 2` because the first 3 appears in position 2 of the array.

For this algorithm assume that the array is already sorted.

I know how to use the binary search, but I don't know how to make it the first `n` in the array instead of the first `n` it finds.

Comment: [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)

Comment: Not regarding to your question, but did you notice that you initialize the array with 12 elements?

Comment: Once you find a match with binary search you can keep going left...

Comment: @nbro That would not be correct since in that case the worst case execution time would go upto O(n).

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya There's no restriction on the running time. In any case, it was the first idea that came to my mind.

Comment: If there is no restriction on running time, why do a binary search? Just start from the first element and do linear search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at std::lower_bound it seems to be what you are looking for

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify binary search slightly to get your answer.I have written a program that will do the needful.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int no,x;
    int A[12345];
    cout<<"Enter no of array elements : ";
    cin>>no;
    cout<<"Enter array elements : ";
    for (int i=0;i<no;i++)
    {
        cin>>A[i];
    }
    cout<<"Enter no to be searched for : ";
    cin>>x;
    int low = 0;
    int high = no-1;
    while(low<high)
    {
        int mid = low + (high-low)/2;
        if (A[mid]>=x)
        {
            high = mid;
        }
        else
        {
            low = mid+1;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Found at : "<<high;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Binary Search First Element function
def BSFE(begin, end, array, num):
    if end-begin <= 1:
        if array[begin] == num:
            return begin
        elif array[end] == num:
            return end
        else:
            return -1
    else: 
        mid = (begin + end) >> 1;
        if array[mid] >= num:
            return BSFE(begin, mid, array, num)
        else:
            return BSFE(mid, end, array, num)

# main
array = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]
n = 3
print(BSFE(0, len(array)-1, array, n))
```

Write in python. You can treat it as a piece of pseudo-code if you only know c++. It's like a simplified version of merge sort.